# A closed subset $B$ of the Hilbert cube such that $\operatorname{Int}(B) = \emptyset$ and $B$ is not a z-set

Tags: gn.general-topology, metric-spaces

$\def\cube{\mathbf Q}$Let $\cube$ be the Hilbert cube. Give an example of a closed subset $B$ of $\cube$ such that $\operatorname{Int}(B) = \emptyset$  and $B$ is not a z-set.

If anyone has any idea to solve this problem, it would help me a lot. I write down some information:

**Definition**. Let $\cube= \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} [0,1]$ with product topology), with metric $d$ such that if $(x_n)_n, (y_n)_n \in \cube$, $d((x_n)_n,(y_n)_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\lvert x_n - y_n\rvert}{2^n}$. Then $B \subseteq \cube$ is a z-set if, for each $\epsilon > 0$, there is a continuous function $f_\epsilon$ from $\cube$ to $\cube \setminus B$ such that $d(f_\epsilon(x),x) < \epsilon$ for all $x \in X$.

I have tried the following, where a $\sigma$z-set is a countable union of z-sets.  (In $\cube$, I think that all $\sigma$z-sets are z-sets.)

**Lemma**. If $B \subseteq \cube$ is a $\sigma$z-set, then $\cube \setminus B$ is a topologically complete, separable metric AR (Absolute Retract).

**Note**. In $\cube$, $B'$ being a retract is equivalent to $B'$ being AR.

Then, I have tried to find an example of a $B \subseteq \cube$ such that $\cube \setminus B$ is not a retract.  By the lemma, this $B$ would not be a $\sigma$z-set.  Then check if this set $B$ has empty interior in $\cube$ and is closed. I could not find such a $B$.

References.

[1] Alejandro Wanes, Sam Nadler Jr. HYPERSPACES: Fundamental and Recent Advances.

[2] [Macías - Una introducción a los retractos absolutos y a los retractos de vecindad absolutos](http://www.scielo.org.co/pdf/rein/v31n2/v31n2a05.pdf).

Comment: The phrasing of your question makes it sound like a question that you were asked to answer. If this is not the case, could you say a bit more about how this problem arose in the context of your research?

Comment: Hi Yemon Choi. This question arose from a postgraduate course that I am currently studying.  I must find the solution to the problem but I can't find the solution so I am looking for suggestions to try other ways.

Comment: The set $\{0\}\times[0,1]^\omega$ is nowhere dense but not a $Z$-set in $[-1,1]\times[0,1]^\omega$. It is even not a $Z_1$-set in $[-1,1]\times[0,1]^\omega$ (which means that some map of the interval stably intersects $\{0\}\times[0,1]^\omega$).

Comment: I changed $\mathbb Q$, which I think is unusual notation for anything but the rational numbers, to $\mathbf Q$ `$\mathbf Q$`; of course you can make it anything else you like.  I also deleted the text-with-emoticon at the end, which doesn't belong; and replaced the $\mathbf{math-mode fakery}$ `$\mathbf{math-mode fakery}$` by **MathJax** `**MathJax**`.

Comment: @LSpice $\mathbf{Q}$ is the traditional printed notation for rational numbers. Anyway, your edit is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A=\{0\} \times [-1,1]^{\Bbb N}$ works as an example, e.g.

For more info on $Z$-sets in $Q$, see *Infinite-dimensional Topology* by Jan van Mill.

Comment: Thanks Henno Brandsma.